# C++ pointer troubles

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having trouble with the following code. I am a java developer trying to teach myself c++. Mainly my code in main() is not inserting anything to the root Node. Can anyone help me. I am sure there is something off with my pointers.

```
class Node{
    public:
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        int data;

    Node(int n){
        data = n;
        right = NULL;
        left = NULL;
    }
};

class BST{

    Node* root;

    public:

    BST(){
        root = NULL;
    }

    void insert(int e){
        pinsert(root, e);
    }

    void pinsert(Node* sr, int e){
        if(sr == NULL){
            sr = new Node(e);
        }
        else{
            if((sr->data) > e ){
                pinsert(sr->left, e);
            }
            else{
                pinsert(sr->right, e);
            }
        }
    }
};


int main(){
    BST tree;
    tree.insert(6);
    tree.insert(7);
}
```

Comment: "C++" + "raw pointers" = "asking for troubles". You did it, you got troubles. Now go learn about standard containers and smart pointers, and grab a book instead of trying things blindly, especially when coming from Java.

Comment: I disagree. If you don't get pointers, DEFINITELY use them for a while. I wouldn't recommend (owning) raw pointers in production code either, but it's extremely important to get what's actually going on (having control over that is, after all, a large part of why we use C++ in the first place).

Comment: @Cubic, pointers are important, right. But you need to get bigger picture before getting into them; you need to know how the language (as in "language + standard library") works; in modern C++, pointers are quite advanced topic, and should not be presented to beginners, as they have no interest in learning them - you don't use raw pointers or containers written by yourself much in C++ (if not `s/much/at all`...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your insert is when you begin with an empty list. When you pass a `Node *` to your `pinsert` function, the argument is passed *by value*, so your function ends up with a *copy* of the pointer. When the pointer is `NULL`, you change the pointer to point to your new node. Since you only have a copy of the pointer in `pinsert`, this only changes the copy of the pointer. When the function returns, the pointer, and the list, is unchanged.

Pass a *reference* to the pointer to get around this:

```
void pinsert(Node *&sr, int e)
```

Now the rest of your code doesn't need to change, and your function can change the pointer.

This problem is analogous to passing object references in java: you can change the *contents* of the object, by setting fields and calling methods, but you can't change the argument to a new object, or to `null`.

Answer (score 6):

You pass `sr` by value and assign to it. This won't change you `root`. Pass it by reference instead:

```
void pinsert( Node*& sr, int e)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `root` is always NULL, you never assign anything to it.

When you call `pinsert(root, e)` and then do this:

```
void pinsert(Node* sr, int e){
    if(sr == NULL){
        sr = new Node(e);
    }
```

you send a copy of root and assign to that copy, not the `root` which remains NULL. You need to either send the pointer by reference (`void pinsert(Node** sr, int e)`) - notice 2 'stars' or `void pinsert(Node*& sr, int e)`.